# MySQL query with PDO

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with sql queries. I have some tables in my database and I want to join them with some conditions to get the result and these conditions are "AND". 
I want that if all these conditions or some of them were "null" my queries work fine.

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT * from(
        SELECT id FROM status WHERE name in("")
    )as t
    INNER JOIN customer
    on FIND_IN_SET(t.id,customer.statuse)>0
            where  customer.customername LIKE '' AND customer.organization LIKE '' AND customer.workfieldid=''
    GROUP BY customer.customerid
)as t2
LEFT JOIN workfield
on workfield.workfieldid=t2.workfieldid
```

Comment: There is not enough information to go on here. Can you share your data layout and what you want your results to be? FYI, this is not a PHP or PDO related question.

Comment: my table is status the field is name and id the result t table return some id i want if status name is null ,t table have all status id

Comment: pleas help me i want search customers table whit some condition that this condition related with AND if one condition is empty i don't  know  my result not null